# How use mailto to send form to email only when user clicks ok in confirmation box?

Tags: javascript, mailto, bootbox

I want to send a form to an email address through mailto integration. I used the following code for this:

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<form action="mailto:myforms@mydomain.com" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="location.href='thanks.html';" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="username" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
        <button class='btn btn-signup btn-signup-sm' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

But I only want the form to be submitted when the user clicks ok in the confirmation box that appears when clicking the sign up button. When he clicks ok he must be guided to a thank you page (onsubmit="location.href='thanks.html'). See the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    bootbox.confirm("Message here", function(result) {
        ("Confirm result: "+result);
}); 
});
});
</script>
```

At the moment the code is not functioning and I don't know how to fix this. Do I perhaps need to include some if statement in the JS code that ensures that the form is only send when clicking ok?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can remove type="submit" and just trigger the form.submit yourself in the callback of click

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by jquery:

```
var data = {
name: $("#form_name").val(),
email: $("#form_email").val(),
message: $("#msg_text").val()
};

var sendMail=function(){
      $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "email.php",
             data: data,
             success: function(){
             //now redirect to thanks.html page
             location.href="thanks.html";
             }
      });

 //call this on btn onclick
 $(".btn").click(sendMail());
```